# Can't Recity Error popping up when setting up neovim packages

Tags: javascript, powershell, terminal, ide, oh-my-posh

I was Trying to setup my terminal for web development

**Reference video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkCnPdaRBE0

but now I removed all configuration files but still i am getting this error

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Autocommands for "*":
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: loop or previous error loading module 'transparent'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

whenever I am using neovim I get this errror and i cant seem to recitify it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4euQ.jpg), how to rectify this?

**What i expected:** back to how neovim was in the beginning
**What happend:** still that error occurs

Comment: If I can read the error correctly, it seems there's an issue trying when loading `module 'transparent'`

Comment: "but now I removed all configuration files" -- what is the output of `:scriptnames`? Seems to me as if there is still some non-default configuration being loaded that you are unaware of.